# custom cursor image disappears after clicking anywhere in page, MAC, Multiple browsers

Tags: jquery, html, css

UIm setting a custom image to the cursor using jQuery like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("body").css('cursor','url(http://affordable-glass.com/test/penguinSm.png),auto');
});
```

This works, however:

1. Making sharp movements with the mouse sometimes makes the cursor go back a non-image cursor. Easiest way to replicate is to move the pointer in small quick circles. (this is a little odd but not a huge deal)
2. **Clicking anywhere makes the cursor revert back to a non-image cursor** (this is the main issue)

Here's a [jsfiddle showing the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/f0wzqvum/1/)

I also tried with CSS directly but got the same issues

```
div{
    cursor: url(http://affordable-glass.com/test/penguinSm.png),auto;
}
```

[CSS Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0wzqvum/1/)

Tested and got same results with each of the below so this seems like it might be expected behaviour.

- Windows, using Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m (run in virtualBox on my mac)
- Mac, using Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit)
- Mac, Firefox version 34.0.5
- **Using Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m run on an actual windows PC Is not affected by this issue**

It seems this might be an issue with my machine?

Here are my specs:
[image]

Comment: I wasn't able to get the image to go away, I moved my mouse in the smallest and quickest circles I could... My hand hurts now.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with Firefox 34 on OS X.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek yeah? Its weird sometimes it just turns back. Then main issue is losing the image when the user clicks though

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara hmmm, I just tried on an actual windows PC and didnt have the issue. The widows I tried before is running in virtualbox on my mac. Now Im wondering if this is a side effect of virtualbox's mouse sharing component....

Comment: Shut down virtualbox, issue persists

Comment: I just tested, it's working properly!

Comment: @SuperHornet what OS are you running?

Comment: @SuperHornet yeah, it's working on my actual windows machine too, just not on my mac or in the virtual windows os running on the mac, its weird. Im going to try a different mac at work tomorrow

Comment: JSFiddle link functions fine for me (Safari/Yosemite)

Comment: @jn_pdx thanks, this is starting to look like a local machine issue. I cant imagine what the issue could be though.

Comment: I tried and I could reproduce. I have a mac with pretty much the same spec as you have. Tried Chrome, Firefix and Safari with not issues at all.

Comment: @applejack42 do you have MS word for mac? if so does it work when it is open? mine stops when I close word but starts again as soon as I re-open it

Comment: I actually have had MS word open this whole time. I closed and reopened with not no issues. Word for Mac 2011 v14.3.5. Are you opening particular large file? Try opening Activity and see if there high CPU/Memory usage when you open/close word. Very strange. Do you have multiple screens?

Comment: @applejack42 I was working on a fairly large document.I do have multiple screens, the built in and two other 20in screens. Also the screens are connected using usb adapters which can be weird with some software. I resarted my mac yesterday and now I cant get it to do it again even with Word open so I guess it was just some weird one off thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug having to do with MS Word or one of it's addons on my Mac. If Word is open the behavior occurs. If I close MS Word, the issue stops. After restarting my mac I am now unable to reproduce the problem, I guess something was just being buggy. Thanks to everyone who tried to help!

Comment: You saved me man, by making me realise the problem was with a specific program being open. For me it was Adobe PS which made this big issue